# Keep R Model in memory for Rest API

Tags: r, rest

We have a GLM R model that is ~ 2 GB in size.  We are using this model to service a REST API.  We need < 3 second response times.  The problem is that using the conventional saveRDS / readRDS functions takes way too long.  Our last option is to find a way to keep the R Model in memory in between sessions.

At a high level:

1. Service a REST API.
2. Keep a multi gigabyte model in memory.
3. Keep response times below 3 seconds.

Stuff we've tried and doesn't work:

1. Shrinking the size of the model.  Our data scientist says that's as small as he can get it.
2. I've experimented with compression and other settings on saveRDS.  The best I could do is 12 seconds to load the model from file.
3. We tried Microsoft R Server.  All the web API requests would be redirected to the same session.  Problem is that we had to wrap a decent amount of code around keeping the session alive.  Even then it would flake out often.
4. Microsoft R Server Real Time is out because it only accepts models generated by the ScaleR.  I know ScaleR has a GLM function, but I've been told its not an option.
5. Faster IO doesn't seem to help.  It appears that the bottleneck is the deserialization of the rData file.  R being single threaded doesn't help.

Edit:
The question is what R for REST API library / service would allow us to statefully keep a model in memory in between calls.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: A 2 GB GLM :thinking: I would double check that you for sure can't make it smaller.

Comment: I think the issue is that the GLM model keeps a copy of the training data on save. Why not just export the coefficients and score manually (i.e. let the API generate the score)? Should be simple enough with a simple linear model since it's just y = Beta1 * var1 + Beta2 * var2... etc.

Comment: As mentioned in another response we want to calculate the confidence and probability intervals.  We are now looking at ways to move this calculation into a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing on my comment from above as well as the suggestion of @TenniStats, the best approach is to reduce the size of the GLM. Consider the following:

```
#generating some sample data that's fairly large
sample.data <- data.frame('target' = sample(c(1:10), size = 5000000, replace = T),
                          'regressor1' = rnorm(5000000),
                          'regressor2' = rnorm(5000000),
                          'regressor3' = rnorm(5000000),
                          'regressor4' = rnorm(5000000),
                          'regressor5' = rnorm(5000000),
                          'regressor6' = rnorm(5000000),
                          'regressor7' = rnorm(5000000),
                          'regressor8' = rnorm(5000000),
                          'regressor9' = rnorm(5000000),
                          'regressor10' = rnorm(5000000))

#building a toy glm - this one is about 3.3 GB
lm.mod <- glm(sample.data, formula = target ~ ., family = gaussian)

#baseline predictions
lm.default.preds <- predict(lm.mod, sample.data)

#extracting coefficients
lm.co <- coefficients(lm.mod)

#applying coefficients to original data set by row and adding intercept
lightweight.preds <- lm.co[1] +
  apply(sample.data[,2:ncol(sample.data)],
        1,
        FUN = function(x) sum(x * lm.co[2:length(lm.co)]))

#clearing names from vector for comparison
names(lm.default.preds) <- NULL

#taa daa
all.equal(lm.default.preds, lightweight.preds)
```

Then we can do the following:

```
#saving for our example and starting timing
saveRDS(lm.co, file = 'myfile.RDS')
start.time <- Sys.time()

#reading from file
coefs.from.file <- readRDS('myfile.RDS')
#scoring function
light.scoring <- function(coeff, new.data) {
  prediction <- coeff[1] + sum(coeff[2:length(coeff)] * new.data)
  names(prediction) <- NULL
  return(prediction)
}

#same as before
light.scoring(coefs.from.file, sample.data[1, 2:11])
#~.03 seconds on my machine
Sys.time() - start.time
```

Comment: Had a chat with our data scientist.  The big problem is that we need to calculate confidence and probability intervals to go along with our predictions.  This gives us a path to go down.